# how to edit and run PLAI code in Emacs with DrRacket 5.2.1

Tags: scheme, racket, plai

I am studying [PLAI](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/), Now I have already run chapter 3's code in DrRacket (with `#lang plai`), but I am a newbie in DrRacket. Can I edit and run the code only in Emacs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `#lang plai` directive will work in ordinary Racket files outside of DrRacket. There should be a `racket` executable in your installation of Racket that you can use to run these. Try [geiser](http://www.nongnu.org/geiser/) if you want an emacs package that makes it easier to run Racket programs. [Quack](http://www.neilvandyke.org/quack/) is also helpful.

More generally, see the [guide entry](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Emacs.html) on using emacs with Racket. You might also want to start reading the guide from [the beginning](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/intro.html) where it starts out by explaining how to run Racket.

Comment: I have already installed Quack, and my DrRacket version is 5.2.1, but I don't know how to make #lang plai directive work, can you help me? Thanks

Comment: You can just run the `racket` executable on the commandline with the file you write (with `#lang` at the top). If you're using Geiser, there is a keyboard shortcut to run the contents of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

A problem you'll run in with Geiser is that "C-x C-b" (`geiser-eval-buffer`) won't work when you have a `#lang` directive in your code.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008623/setting-language-with-lang-in-the-repl) has a couple of workarounds for Geiser. Alternatively, you could use [racket-mode](https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode), which aims to replicate in Emacs the DrRacket experience, where the focus is on (re)running the code or tests from a clean slate, rather than incrementally in REPL. (For the philosophy behind this, see Matthias Felleisen's [blog post](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2009/03/the-drscheme-repl-isnt-the-one-in-emacs.html).)

(Note: racket-mode still includes bindings for sending the current buffer's region or sexps to the REPL, it's just that there is no special support for switching modules and namespaces. Which, especially at the beginning end, many people won't miss anyways.)